# Apex returning rows but no data

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, custom-object

I have created a simple VF page with an Apex controller which fetches records from a custom object.

The VF page displays the correct number of rows but no data is returned. I know that it is getting the correct number of rows because if I add a LIMIT clause in the SOQL it is reflected on the VF table.

**VF**:

```
<apex:page controller="ServiceStatusController">
...
    <apex:dataTable value="{!serviceitems}" var="item" id="theTable" 
styleClass="tableClass" columnClasses="col-service, col-info, col-status">
           <apex:column >
                 <apex:facet name="header">Service</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!item.id}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column >
                 <apex:facet name="header">Information</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!item.information__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column >
                 <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                 <apex:outputText value="{!item.name}"/>
           </apex:column>           
     </apex:dataTable>
```

**Apex**:

```
public class ServiceStatusController {
    public list<Service_Status__c> lstItem;

    public LIST<Service_Status__c> getServiceItems() {
        lstItem = new list<Service_Status__c>();
        lstItem = [SELECT Id, Name, Information__c FROM Service_Status__c];
        return lstItem;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't address your problem, but your current controller contains redundant lines of code and leaves the list items in the view state when (given the current logic) it doesn't have to. This is all the code you need:

```
public class ServiceStatusController {
    public LIST<Service_Status__c> getServiceItems() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Information__c FROM Service_Status__c];
    }
}
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your page. Two suggestions:

- Are you checking the page using a "System Administrator" profile (to eliminate object and field access rights)?
- Use your browser's "View Page Source" to confirm that the data values are missing from the table (and not just hidden by CSS styling).

Comment: You're bang on, it was because of lack permissions for the logged in user.